# Calling IDENT_CURRENT against a different database

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2016

I'm trying to call [`IDENT_CURRENT()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/ident-current-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) against a different database without moving to that database but I can't seem to find the schema it belongs to.  I tried both `sys` and `dbo` but neither worked.  I've searched and searched but nowhere can I find anything relating to either it's schema or how to call it.

How do you go about running such functions on another database please?  I know I can most likely create a function in that database and then call my function but I'm first trying to find out whether there's an easier way.

Thanks!

Comment: I think you should first create a Synonym for the table on the other server,and then pass that  synonym name  to the IDENT_CURRENT().Do let me know if that works.

Comment: @Zee786, for the other server, I'd simply use an `OPENQUERY`: `SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY( [Server], N'SELECT IDENT_CURRENT( N''[DB].[Schema].[Table]'' );' );`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`IDENT_CURRENT` is a function, it doesn't belong to a schema.
You can provide it with a 3-parts identifier to a table that belongs on a different database in the same server:

```
SELECT IDENT_CURRENT('<Database>.<Schema>.<Table>');
```

However you should note that `ident_current` might yield wrong results.

For more information, read Aaron Bertrand's [For the last time, NO, you can't trust IDENT_CURRENT()](https://sqlperformance.com/2014/01/t-sql-queries/ident-current).

Comment: Ah, so it's a function of SQL Server itself, I was under the impression that all "functions" were written against the sys schema.  Regarding the `IDENT_CURRENT`, I don't have any other option as there are `INSTEAD OF` triggers on many of the tables, it's not used in any way that'll cause a problem though.

Comment: Glad to help, though I can't imagine the context in which getting the identity value of a table in a different database may be useful - I'll bet you have your reasons, though.